# iPhone doesn't receive calls on first attempt

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-carriers

When someone phones my iPhone 7, the caller just hears a "boop boop boop boop" sequence (same pitch) before the call is ended - my iPhone doesn't ring at all, but still gives me a notification of a missed call. If they phone again immediately after, this time the call goes through like normal, ringing on both ends.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Your cellular carrier would have the diagnostic ability to see what the cell tower did - what the phone radio did and why the first call wasn’t routed to your local tower in a timely manner. We all may speculate but this would be a great self answer once you worked this with your carrier tech support. Nothing different with android or iPhone or any other cellular network call TBH.

Comment: Have you got Do Not Disturb, Silent mode or any Focus enabled?

Comment: @Thinkr yep, I have had a custom Focus enabled for as long as I've had the phone. Turns out that that Focus had _Calls from > No one_ set. So far it looks like changing that to _Everyone_ has fixed the problem. Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: @theonlygusti No problem, I'll also include other possible causes. ;)

Comment: I think the question actually has nothing to do with [cellular-carriers], because the behaviour I observed is just the normal and expected behaviour of Focus/Do not Disturb...

Comment: It is carrier based @theonlygusti.  When you miss/reject/busy an incoming call, it’s *forwarded* to VM by the carrier.  Since yours isn’t setup (stated in comments below) the VM service is erroring the call out and dropping it.  Focus is allowing the *second* call through, but you’ll continue to have errors when busy or missed calls regardless of Silent setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems that you have a Focus enabled which blocks calls but allows them if repeated.

To disable this, you can go to *Settings > Focus > [Focus name]*, and, under Allow Notifications, choose "People". Then, go to the "Calls From" section and select "Favorites" or "All Contacts" (you must've selected "No One" before). You can also just turn off the Focus.

In that section, you must've also had "Allow Repeated Calls" enabled (or you wouldn't have gotten the call the second time).

[image]

<sup>Click to open full size</sup>

For more information and guidance on this, check out the [Allow or silence notifications for a Focus on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph21d43af5b/ios) Apple Support article.

Note: This can also happen because you've got Silent mode enabled.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is incorrect.

> the caller just hears a "boop boop boop boop" sequence (same pitch) before the call is ended…

First, the tone that’s heard is a [carrier disconnect tone](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmW50NkbWLGilbFLGiLQxYYS59OQ_A).  This occurs when the call cannot be completed for whatever reason, then dropped.

When you put your phone on *Silent* all it does it silence the ringer.  The phone will continue to receive the call, you just won’t hear it (it may vibrate if you enabled Haptic Feedback), and you’ll still be notified of a missed call.

> my iPhone doesn't ring at all, but still gives me a notification of a missed call.

When you put your phone on *Do Not Disturb* via a Focus, it will reject calls and **immediately send them to your voice mail**.  So, if people calling you and you have your phone on a Focus/DnD, they should be immediately sent to voice mail - based on your description, this isn’t happening.

#### There’s a Voice Mail issue

Your callers are getting the tone then, when they call back, they get through indicating a Focus is enabled ***and*** there’s an issue with voice mail.

**Why voice mail?**

When you reject or miss a call, it is *forwarded* somewhere else (voice mail isn’t local to your phone).  If it’s not set up or there’s an issue with it, the call will be dropped and you’ll receive those disconnect tones.

**How can you confirm this?**

Ask a caller if they got your voice mail greeting.  Given (in your original question) that they said they only got tones, it appears there’s an issue with voice mail.  Remember, callers will be directed to your voice mail even if your phone is off (or even destroyed).

#### Why is changing Focus not a solution?

Basically, you’ve lost that functionality if voice mail isn’t working properly.  The idea behind Focus is to reject calls *to your voicemail* so you aren’t disturbed.  When you are subsequently called back becase the caller thought the call failed, it “breaks” Focus - not what it was designed for.

Additionally, if you have to turn off Focus to allow your phone to work as it should, you’ve defeated the purpose of it.  The issue here is related to your voice mail.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147016/discussion-on-answer-by-allan-iphone-doesnt-receive-calls-on-first-attempt); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.